# How to set timeout at camel servlet route

Tags: servlets, apache-camel, settimeout

I want to set the timeout at servlet route.

```
public class MyCamelRoute extends RouteBuilder {


    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        restConfiguration()
                .component("servlet")
                .enableCORS(true)
                .contextPath("/")
                .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json);
        onException(IOException.class)
                    .handled(true)
                    .process(bean:handleProcess);

        rest("/get").get(/user).to("direct:getusers");
        from("direct:getusers")
                .prpcess(bean:exchangeProcess)
                .to("http4:xx:8080/getuser?httpClient.connectTimeout=1000&bridgeEndpoint=true")
                .process(xxx)
                .to(xxxx)....
;
```

If someone call the GET../get/user take too long, this service will cancel the request itself. 
like connect timeout and return timeout exception, assign status code 504.

I don't know how to do it or any option that I can use or change.

Can someone help me out with this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You already use `httpClient.connectTimeout=1000`, try to add `httpClient.soTimeout=100` to the URI for a request timeout (socket timeout) of 100ms

If the timeout is reached, the underlying httpClient probably throws an Exception that you can handle with a Camel Exception clause.

```
onException(WhateverExceptionOccursOnTimeout.class)...
```

Comment: I think it might be a misunderstanding, it will work if to() [GET http:xx:8080/getuser] timeout. But I mean that it doesn't work when process() timeout. I have a lot of process() need to do at this route[GET../get/user].

Comment: No, `.process` or `.bean` do not know a timeout because they are used to call a Java method. Timeouts are used when an application makes external calls. As in your case, when your processor makes an HTTP call, you have to configure the HttpClient you use for the call accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add these ones.

connectionRequestTimeout

connectTimeout

[https://camel.apache.org/components/2.x/http4-component.html][1]